# Show filename tail and parent directory in statusline

Tags: statusline

If I'm at file `/a/b/c/foo.txt`, I'd like the statusline to display `c/foo.txt`. Is this possible?

The reason for this is that for web development, too many files are named `index.js` to make just the tail useful, while the full path (or relative path) is too long to make it easy to parse.

The only relevant statusline options I see are:

- `%f` which is the path relative to the current directory
- `%F` the full path to the file
- `%t` only the filename (tail).

Comment: Using the default `%f` I would simply `cd /a/b/` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include arbitrary expressions in your status line with `%{}`. Try this:

```
:set statusline=%{expand('%:p:h:t')}/%t
```

This finds the tail of the head of the full path (i.e. just the parent directory) and then tacks on filename using the `%t` item you already mentioned.

See `:help expand()` for more details.